# Can I use pdfbox print with old printers that do not support pdf?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am implementing a printing tool for printing PDF document, I am testing it with printers that support PDF, but I wonder if it will work with some of our client printers which do not support PDF.

Code:

```
PrintService printerService = getPrinterService(printerName);
            PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(documentStream);
            Doc document = new SimpleDoc(new PDFPageable(pdf), DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, null);
            DocPrintJob job = printerService.createPrintJob();
```

Comment: I don't think that printers care about the file format on the PCs

Comment: Yes if your OS has a printer driver for that printer. PDFBox uses java 
to print and java uses the printer driver. There is no direct pdf to 
printer. Maybe you're confusing PDF with Postscript, which are both by 
Adobe.

Comment: Thanks Tilman,
Do you mean that PDFBox does not send PDF file directly to the printer?

Comment: @sahbijabnouni no it doesn't. If it did, then there wouldn't be a need for PDFBox at all - think about it.